# OnActivityResult is called after shared element transition end

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using shared element transition when navigate from activity A to activity B.

My issue - calling of `SupportFinishAfterTransition` in activity B makes `OnActivityResult` called after `OnTransitionEnd` with small interval in activity A. So my UI (`ImageView`) in activity A is "flashing" because of image source updating with interval.

I need `OnActivityResult` to be called first to update my UI and then play exit transition.

My code:
Activity A:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Some code
    Window.SharedElementExitTransition.AddListener(this);
}
```

This code called firstly:

```
public void OnTransitionEnd(global::Android.Transitions.Transition transition)
{
}
```

This code called secondly, but I would like to firstly:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Activity B:

```
SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
SupportFinishAfterTransition();
```

Comment: Share the code segment you are talking about.

Comment: Ok, it's done, thanks

Answer (score 2):

use **onActivityReenter** instead of OnActivityResult. onActivityReenter executes before activity displayed, OnActivityResult executes after activity displayed.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityReenter(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
             //do your work here

             //example of getting data:
             int someData = data.getIntExtra("EXTRA_CODE", -1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware of these things when you want have a transition after returning from `startActivityForResult`:

i.) you need to specify a `windowSharedElementReenterTransition`, usually only `windowSharedElementEnterTransition` and `windowSharedElementEnterTransition` are specified.

ii.) in the `onActivityReenter` of the reentered Activity you need to call `postponeEnterTransition()`, then update your views as desired and call again `startPostponedEnterTransition()`.

`onActivityResult` is only called when the previous Activity is finished, whereas `onActivityReenter` is called when the previous Activity is still running (you can get the Intent there to update the UI).

Here is an article which brings light into the dark:
https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/03/activity-postponed-shared-element-transitions-part3b.html